# SSRS Report, dates to auto generate the last 3 weeks,

Tags: reporting-services, time, ssrs-2012

I have a report that I need to show the last 4 weeks of totals that I would like them to be 'week ending 18/12, 11/12 , 4/12 and 27/11 etc'

is there a way that I can hard code these into my report expression so they will auto change every week.

Comment: Currently Using this which works

Comment: =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2-WeekDay(Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today))

but struggling adding the format to it.

Comment: What do you mean by adding the format? Can you explain in little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

About the date formatting issue : there should be 2 good options for this.

First option is to use the "Format" property of a component and enter `d/MM`.

Second option is to use the Format expression as such : `=Format(Now(), "d/MM")` where you have to replace the `Now()` with your date. Note that if you get an error with this expression, you might need to wrap it with a CDate : `=Format(CDate(Now()), "d/MM")`